# Do I need sticky sessions with websockets?

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to scale socket.io with cluster.

I read on the socket.io website that I need to enable [sticky sessions](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session). But why? When I make a websocket connection that connection should be maintained until the client disconnects right? Hence no need for sticky sessions, I assume that's only needed in cases of disconnects or some other type of transport that requires multiple connection requests.

Comment: There are many reasons that a client might momentarily lose a socket.io connection and reconnect automatically (power save, network interruption, etc...).  If your app needs them to reconnect to the same cluster endpoint, then you will need some sort of stickiness to make that happen when they reconnect.  Assuming a 100% reliable network connection that never has a glitch is risky.

Comment: @jfriend00 if I use a redis adaptor I wouldn't need to reconnect to the same node right?

Comment: Correct, because then you'd be storing the state centrally so any node could fetch the desired state.  You would still need a cookie to identify the user and be able to fetch the appropriate state in redis for a given incoming connection.

Comment: @jfriend00 im also planning on implementing something like this. just wondering if the redis-adapter stores anything. it says it does pub sub